# Error: fazer uma consulta(query) no dao que é um alias

Tags: java, postgresql

Essa query fuciona normalmente no postgreSQL:

```
select nome as "pessoas?" from pessoa
```

Mas no java eu fiz um dao que tem um método chamado encontrarAlias:

```
sql = "select nome as 'teste?' from pessoa where id=?";
```

Dá a mensagem:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'teste?'"

PS.:Estou utilizando PreparedStatement.

```
@Override
    public Pessoa enncontrarAlias(int id) {
    Pessoa pessoa = null;

    sql = "select nome as \"teste?\" from pessoa where id=?";

    try {
        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            pessoa = new Pessoa();
            pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        }

        rs.close();

        return pessoa;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

         throw new RuntimeException(e);     }   
}
```

Comment: O que é "teste?"? O que você pretende com essa interrogação? O PreparedStatement está entendendo isso como se ele fosse um parametro.

Comment: 'teste?' é o nome do alias, sei lá poderia ser 'nomes?'. Mas precisa ter a interrogação que estou fazendo um teste aqui...

Comment: Tem como você adicionar como está declarando e executando a query pelo PreparedStatement?

Comment: @DiegoF tá aí, editei. olha.

Comment: Continua dando erro?

Comment: Quando vc remove o `?` funciona?

Comment: SIM. mesmo tirando dá erro

Comment: Qual versão do postgres está usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não usa aspas simples como escape de caractares no postgres e sim aspas duplas, nesse caso adicione uma barra para fazer o escape no java.

```
sql = "select nome as \"teste?\" from pessoa where id=?";
```

Para recuperar as informações do banco de dados use o alias:

```
rs.getString("teste?")
```

Comment: vou testar aqui amigo. :D

Comment: rray acho que irá dar problema mesmo assim, o preparedStatement reconhece uma `?` como um parametro a ser passado.

Comment: @DiegoF é uma boa pergunta hehe não tenho certeza mas ele deve ignorar essa interrogação, pelo menos baseado no erro da pergunta.

Comment: : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A nome da coluna nome não foi encontrado neste ResultSet.
 at dao.PessoaDAO.enncontrarAlias(PessoaDAO.java:161)

Comment: parece que está funfando...espera

Comment: @gonz na hora de pegar o valor do banco vc fez assim: `pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("teste?"));` ?

Comment: @gonz funcionou? era só colocar o `rs.getString("teste?")` ?

Comment: antes de vc escrever isso eu testei aqui. deu certo;